# Data Studio Regex - Exclude www

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Using Google Data Studio, I have a regex;

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*/(.*)/' )
```

Is what I am currently using. The page variable is being re-created to a Last Page Path, but I need to ensure the Page does not include 'www'.

Any ideas or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*www.*|.*/(.*)/' )` will work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

That works, it does return an empty result for ones that include 'www' which is fine!

Is there any way to include more than one exclusion, i.e 'www' or 'http'?

Comment: Yes, `'.*(?:www|http).*|.*/(.*)/'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with empty matches where no results are expected you can leverage the fact that `REGEXP_EXTRACT` only returns a *capturing group value*. Thus, you may specify an alternative before the one you need to get without using capturing groups there.

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*www.*|.*/(.*)/' )
```

This pattern will match and consume a string with `www` in it, and if there is no `www`, the second alternative will trigger, and if there are two slashes, you will get the value between the two rightmost slashes.

If you need to also skip strings with `http` in them simply replace `www` with `(?:www|http)`, a non-capturing group matching `www` or `http`:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Page , '.*(?:http|www).*|.*/(.*)/' )
```